# JSON Database update loosing key values

Tags: php, arrays, json, database

I got this in my DB (23 is my picture ID):

```
{"23" : {"13x18":"5","20X30":"5","30x45":"4","digital":"4"}}
```

I want to add another data just like this one in the same spot so it would look like this :

```
["23" : {"13x18":"5","20X30":"5","30x45":"4","digital":"4"}, 
"42" : {"13x18":"2","20X30":"1","30x45":"3","digital":"1"}]
```

Here is the code is use :

```
$clientChoice = [];
$clientChoice[$post['picId']] = $test;
$select = (new GalleryCategoriesModel)->findByUrl($post['url']);
if($select['clientChoice'] != null){
    $tabs = json_decode($select['clientChoice'], true);
    $new = array_merge($tabs, $clientChoice);
    $chosen = json_encode($new);
} else {
    $chosen = json_encode($clientChoice);
}
$update = (new GalleryCategoriesModel)->update(['clientChoice'=>$chosen], $post['id']);
```

And here is the result i got with it :

```
[{"13x18":"5","20X30":"5","30x45":"4","digital":"4"},
{"13x18":"2","20X30":"1","30x45":"3","digital":"1"}]
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

----------------- CORRECTION ------------------

Thanks to the answer given, here is what i do now :

```
    $clientChoice = [];
    $clientChoice[$post['picId']] = $test;

    $select = (new GalleryCategoriesModel)->findByUrl($post['url']);

    if($select['clientChoice'] != null){
        $tabs = json_decode($select['clientChoice'], true);
        $new = $tabs + $clientChoice;
        $chosen = json_encode($new);
    } else {
        $chosen = json_encode($clientChoice);
    }

    $update = (new GalleryCategoriesModel)->update(['clientChoice'=>$chosen], $post['id']);
```

And here is what I got in my DB :

```
{"25":{"13x18":"1","20X30":"3","30x45":"5","digital":"1"},
"37":{"13x18":"4","20X30":"8","30x45":"3","digital":"2"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with your call to `array_merge`. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> Values in the input arrays with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array

So your two arrays that have keys of `23` and `42` end up merged as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [13x18] => 5
            [20X30] => 5
            [30x45] => 4
            [digital] => 4
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [13x18] => 2
            [20X30] => 1
            [30x45] => 3
            [digital] => 1
        )
)
```

You can work around this by using the [array union operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) (`+`), which will preserve the keys from both arrays (although it will ignore `$clientChoice` if the key is the same as one already existing in `$tabs`), however since they are `id` values I assume this should not occur.

```
$new = $tabs + $clientChoice;
```

In this case, `$new` contains:

```
Array
(
    [23] => Array
        (
            [13x18] => 5
            [20X30] => 5
            [30x45] => 4
            [digital] => 4
        )
    [42] => Array
        (
            [13x18] => 2
            [20X30] => 1
            [30x45] => 3
            [digital] => 1
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mfgDR)

Comment: Thank you very much, sometimes it's just in front of us and we can see it :) i edit with your correction.

PS : ( the final result in my DB isnt between [ ] but i got my ID and my sizes ) 

{"25":{"13x18":"1","20X30":"3","30x45":"5","digital":"1"},
"37":{"13x18":"4","20X30":"8","30x45":"3","digital":"2"}}

Comment: @Shogu23 indeed, sometimes you just need that second pair of eyes. In terms of output, I've printed the arrays rather than the JSON, if you edit the demo I gave to `echo $chosen;` instead of `print_r($new);` you'll see the result is as you expect.